# Can a class with consteval constructor be created on heap in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, new-operator, consteval

In the following code `struct A` has immediate function default constructor, and an object of the struct is created in the dynamic memory be means of `new A{}`:

```
struct A {       
    consteval A() {}
};

int main() {
    new A{};
}
```

Only Clang accepts it.

GCC complains

```
error: the value of '<anonymous>' is not usable in a constant expression
    6 |     new A{};
      |           ^
note: '<anonymous>' was not declared 'constexpr'
```

And MSVC does as well:

```
error C7595: 'A::A': call to immediate function is not a constant expression
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6Px5WYGzd

Which compiler is right here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Which compiler is right here?

Invoking a `consteval` constructor with `new` is ill-formed.
MSVC and GCC are right to reject it; clang is wrong as a diagnostic is required.

---

```
struct A { consteval A() {} };
```

`consteval` makes `A::A()` an *immediate function*<sup>1</sup>.

An immediate function can only be called from<sup>2,3</sup>:

- another immediate function, or
- a consteval if statement, or
- a constant expression<sup>4</sup>.

`new A{}` is none of the above.

---

<sup>1)</sup> [`[dcl.constexpr]/2`](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#2.sentence-2)

> A `constexpr` or `consteval` specifier used in the declaration of a function declares that function to be a constexpr function.
> A function or constructor declared with the `consteval` specifier is called an *immediate function*.

<sup>2)</sup> [`[expr.prim.id.general]/4`](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.general#4)

> A potentially-evaluated id-expression that denotes an immediate function shall appear only
> (4.1) as a subexpression of an immediate invocation, or
> (4.2) in an immediate function context.

<sup>3)</sup> [`[expr.const]/13`](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#13)

> An expression or conversion is in an immediate function context if it is potentially evaluated and either:
> (13.1) its innermost enclosing non-block scope is a function parameter scope of an immediate function, or
> (13.2) its enclosing statement is enclosed ([stmt.pre]) by the compound-statement of a consteval if statement ([stmt.if]).

> An expression or conversion is an immediate invocation if it is a potentially-evaluated explicit or implicit invocation of an immediate function and is not in an immediate function context.
> An immediate invocation shall be a constant expression.

<sup>4)</sup> [`[expr.const]/11.2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#11.2)

> A constant expression is either a glvalue core constant expression that refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant expression whose value satisfies the following constraints:
> (11.2) if the value is of pointer type, it contains the address of an object with static storage duration, the address past the end of such an object ([expr.add]), the address of a non-immediate function, or a null pointer value,

Comment: Note that the code would be fine (in theory) *within* constant expression evaluation, since C++20 does let you allocate memory in constant evaluation... as long as you properly deallocate it. So `A` could be heap-allocated in a constant expression context.

Comment: @NicolBolas like so https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8fY1bEj5E ?

Comment: @YSC The code in the link should still be ill-formed, because the new-expression is still not in an _immediate function context_ and therefore an _immediate invocation_, which by itself needs to be a _constant expression_, right? And I think the same is true for e.g. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/azETn746h?

Comment: @user the key word is "potentially-evaluated" in expr.prim.id.general/4. I don't know the answer though. I need to get back on track regarding all the x-evaluated expressions.

Comment: Not that I know for sure, but _potentially-evaluated_ seems to only exclude contexts of _unevaluated operands_ and I can't find mention of that term which would be relevant. It might be worth a new question. Maybe @NicolBolas would answer it.